# Displaying an "empty" block

Tags: html, css

I have a page layout that [looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc86M.png)...basically a page title, a set of thumbnails down the left arranged in two columns, and a third column which contains the big version of the thumbnail.
My issue is that I have quite a gap between the top of the big image and the top of the page (because the page title is a simple paragraph marker). I can fix this by bringing the title into the top of the first column, but then [I end up with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhYmw.png).
What I want is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhIJC.png) I could add a small piece of text in to the right of the title, but my background colour is not uniform and so it will stand out. Plus, it's not a very elegant solution. I could do it with tables and span the title across two cells, but I don't want to use tables.

Any and all great ideas appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT - added code snippets - this is what I currently have, and equates to the first picture I posted.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  slides[slideIndex-1].classList.add("stickyimage");
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
.bgimg {
 background-image:url('Images/Draw/inkcircle_10pc_opacity.jpg')
}

.image7column {
  float: left;
  width: 14.28%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.bigcolumn {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 71%;
 height: 1400px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Image_handler.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smallcss.css">
    <title>Images</title>
  </head>
  <body class="bgimg" onload="showSlides(1)";>
 <p> Images </p>

    <div class="image7column">
      <img src="Images/Draw/im1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:180px" alt="Image1">
      <img src="Images/Draw/im2.jpg" style="width:100%;height:180px" alt="Image2">
    </div>
 
    <div class="image7column">
      <img src="Images/Draw/im3.jpg" style="width:100%;height:180px" alt="Image3">
      <img src="Images/Draw/im4.jpg" style="width:100%;height:180px" alt="Image4"> 
    </div>   
 
<!-- Big column stuff in here   -->

  <div class="bigcolumn">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <img src="Images/Draw/im1.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" alt="big image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
      <img src="Images/Draw/im2.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" alt="big image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="Images/Draw/im3.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" alt="big image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="Images/Draw/im4.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" alt="big image 4">
    </div>

  </div> <!-- End of bigcolumn -->
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have any code you can add to your question?

Comment: I've added the bear minimum code, but you will have to image the images and the background image as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some help can you provide your html and CSS. I can take a look, but I will not do all your code. 
But If i understand your issue you should do a thing like this :
For your issue you should create 1 main column that contains the 2 other columns and have a thing like this.

```
 <div id ="main-column">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <div id="column-container">
          <div id="column1">
            Column 1
          </div>
        <div id="column2">
          Column 2
         </div>    
    </div>  
</div>
```

With the H1 taking all the width of the main-column, and for the column-container you can use flex, or for the 2 colums use the css property width : 50%, if your main-column width is defined